# what is difference between object relational mapping and data access layer in mvvm?

Tags: c#, mvvm

in my mvvm project  there is one interface which contain add,update,delete interface.therefore interface is data access layer.the code for that are:

```
public interface IAccountDataSource
{
    bool Add(Account account);
    bool Update(Account account);
    bool Remove(Account account);

    Account GetById(int id);
    Account GetByName(string name);
    IEnumerable<Account> GetByCategory(AccountCategory accountCategory);
    IEnumerable<Account> GetBySearchTerm(string searchTerm);
    IEnumerable<Account> GetAll();

    event EventHandler<ObjectAddedEventArgs> AccountAdded;
    event EventHandler<ObjectUpdatedEventArgs> AccountUpdated;
    event EventHandler<ObjectRemovedEventArgs> AccountRemoved;
}
enter code here
```

can any one say data access layer means ORM or not.?what is the advantage of data access layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you show here is some sort of [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). The Repository usually (but not always) talks to a ORM (the object relational mapper) which converts objects into SQL queries (or vice versa).

As to what the advantage is:

Now that you only query the database through your data access layer, you can replace the layer (by implementing/mocking its interface) by mock or stub objects for unit testing. This way you can execute your tests without actually writing something in the database, because your stub/mocks don't actually do anything. Another advantage is that it's easier to replace the data source by another data source (i.e. moving from relational databases to NoSQL) because all your data access code is in one place.

Comment: i say about iaccountdatasource.

Comment: Can do please do something about your English? It's pretty poor and hard to read. But I understand that you're wondering whether 'Repository' and 'Data access layer' are the same things? Well, the data access layer (DAL) just contains stuff that gives 'access' to the 'data', so that may be repositories, but it may as well be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

A data access layer allows you to abstract away the implementation of how you access data,  and will be different depending on where that data is stored (i.e.:databse, file system, etc.)

You could use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) to implement your data access layer in the case where you would like to map data stored in a database to some kind of set of objects.

That being said, your interface looks like it is enforcing a repository pattern approach.

Comment: No. Mvvm is another pattern altogether. If you would like to know more about ORM, take a look at NHibernate.